# Почему в windows 10, в ie, Angular 1.5.8 возникает ошибка "Отказано в доступе" при XMLHttpRequest xhr.open('put', 'http://localhost', true)

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, xmlhttprequest, angular-routing, angular

Разрабатываю программу на Angular 1.5.8

Одну и ту же функцию запускаю при загрузке страницы и  по вставке из буфера обмена и почему-то, при загрузке все нормально отправляется, а при вставке из буфера обмена в windows 10 в IE (в других браузерах работает) при запуске функции

```
XMLHttpRequest xhr.open('put', 'http://localhost:62631/api/PlantConsignee/', true);
```

появляется ошибка "Недопустимый аргумент.", а если через ангуляр обертку

> PlantConsignee.query( Появляется ошибка: "Отказано в доступе" Error:
>   Отказано в доступе.

```
//--------------------------- Error -------------------------------------
at Anonymous function
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:125:278)
 at n
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:122:53)
 at Anonymous function
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:119:255)
 at Anonymous function
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:154:10)
 at m.prototype.$eval
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:168:336)
 at m.prototype.$digest
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:165:412)
 at m.prototype.$apply
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:169:111)
 at Anonymous function
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:299:245)
 at w.event.dispatch
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:2:41706)
 at y.handle
 (http://localhost:62631/prodaction/script/node_modules.min.js?ver=0.6.6688.17819:2:39718)

//----------------------------------------------------------------


.factory('PlantConsignee', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/PlantConsignee/:id', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        save: {
            method: 'POST'
        },
        getAll: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/PlantConsignee/All'
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        query: {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'api/PlantConsignee/Put'
        }
    });
})

//----------------------------------------------------------------


function planttetst() {

  console.log("Запрос заводов");
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('put', 'http://localhost:62631/api/PlantConsignee/', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  var inp = JSON.stringify({ "pageNumber": 1, "pageSize": 9999, "Count": 9999, "Items": [{ "Id": 1, "PlantCode": "**", "Code": "BP00016238" }] });
  xhr.send(inp);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var response = xhr.responseText;
      console.log("ответ заводов" + response.toString());
  }

  PlantConsignee.query({ "pageNumber": 1, "pageSize": 9999, "Count": 9999, "Items": [{ "Id": 1, "PlantCode": "**", "Code": "BP00016238" }] }).$promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log("Запрос заводов мал" + (new Date).toString());
    alert("super");
  }).catch(function (reason) {
    notifyService.error("Ошибка при загрузке справочника завод planttetst1" + ((reason === undefined || reason === null || reason.data === undefined) ? "" : reason.data.message) + ". Повторите попытку через 5 минут");
  });

    }
```

При этом я давала полные админские права к этому сайту, добавляла в зону местной интрасети, не помогает, он даже локально эту ссылку не запускает.
Пыталась понижать версию ангуляр, не помогло. 
Повышать версию ангуляр у меня получается только до 1.5.9, потом пути ломаются и вообще приложение недоступно становится

И главное, эта ошибка возникает только в IE, в хроме все доступно:/

Answer (score 0):

Я решила эту проблему обернув вызов с помощью setTimeout().
 Например:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        XMLHttpRequest xhr.open('put', 'http://localhost:62631/api/PlantConsignee/', true);
    }, 1);
```

Я думаю, что это какая-то ошибка в IE. Всего 1 миллисекунда это все, что нужно!

Очень помог этот вопрос [IE 11 error - Access is denied - XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891783/ie-11-error-access-is-denied-xmlhttprequest?rq=1)
 и ответ.